# 4k Monitors 30hz mouse lag

Tags: display, hdmi

I have a computer that I need to run about 15 meters or 50 feet away from the monitors.  Currently I have two DVI monitors that have resolution of about 2500x1600.  I want to run two 4k monitors instead 3840 x 2160.  Since this is run very far I have to transfer the signal to something else to run it.  I have already purchased two Gefen 4k HDMI to Cat5 converters http://www.gefen.com/kvm/gtb-hdmi-3dtv-blk.jsp?prod_id=9420  Everything else I saw displayport converters extenders ext does not run full 3840 x 2160.  The Gefen ones only run 30hz though.  This is not Gefens fault but a limitation of hdmi.

With 30hz a see a mouse lag.  I am fine with the video and look of the monitor though.  Question is, is there a way to get rid of the mouse lag?  I purchased the computer 5 or so years ago so it is time for a new one.  I was thinking an i7 6 core 3.5 or the i7 8 core extreme 3.0.  Do you think this and a 4gb video card will remove the mouse lag?  Or is mouse lag on 30hz just a defect of 30hz no matter what processing power you have?

Answer (score 5):

The input lag you're perceiving is due to the 30Hz refresh rate.

You will not be able to reduce the perceived choppy mouse movement in any way other that increasing the refresh rate of the display.

Answer (score 4):

I just spent 3 weeks banging on this problem and wrote up a summary of the solutions and workarounds 
http://www.urtech.ca/2017/03/sovled-fix-mouse-lag-4k-screens/

I surely would have loved to seen a single coherent list of ways to solve the mouse lag on 4K screens when I started.  There are many 'hair brain" recommendations floating around the internet that seems to be designed to waste your time or get into arguments.

I truly hope this helps you.  :)

Comment: Please write a proper answer not a comment or your opinion read [How to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: This actually helped me. I didn't know that my HDMI ports had different refresh rate capabilities. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, and what worked for me was that I plugged my HDMI cable into the HDMI 2 Port instead of the HDMI 1 Port, because the HDMI 1 port only had a refresh rate of 30 hz whereas the HDMI2 Port had a refresh rate of 60 hz. In sum, make sure your HDMI port has a refresh rate of 60 hz. It should show it in the "Information" section of the Display Menu of your monitor (the menu that you can bring up pressing the button on the back of the monitor). Keep in mind this is for a Samsung monitor so it may be different for yours. Hope this helps anybody who runs into this problem :)

Answer (score -2):

You need a gaming mouse with a polling rate of 1000. I had same issue untill I bought a razer basilisk mouse